# compare number and variable in assemblyx86

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att

This code reads data from an inputfile character by character and it writes to another file.
It should stop to read and write once it finds a character with value equal to 3.
I said should because the program doesn't stop once it finds a value equal to 3, instead it continues to read until the end of file.

Inputfile is like: `2 4 5 3 1 8`

My code is:

```
.section .data

  varInputHandle: .long 100
  varOutputHandle: .long 100
  varExitCode: .long 1
  cont: .long 1
.section .bss
  .lcomm varBuffer, 1        

.section  .text              # declaring our .text segment
  .globl _start              # telling where program execution should start

_start:

    popl %eax       # Get the number of arguments
    popl %ebx       # Get the program name

    # open input file first 
    popl %ebx       # Get the first actual argument - file to read
    movl $5, %eax       # open
    movl $0, %ecx       # read-only mode
    int $0x80
    movl %eax, varInputHandle   #store input file handle to memory

    #open output file, make it writable, create if not exists
    popl %ebx           # Get the second actual argument - file to write
    movl $5, %eax       # open 
    movl $0101, %ecx    # create flag + write only access (if google is telling me truth)
    movl $0666, %edx    #permissions for out file as rw-rw-rw-
    int $0x80
        movl %eax, varOutputHandle #store output file handle to memory

contToZero:
movl $0, cont
processingLoop:
    incb cont
    #read single char to varBuffer
    movl $3, %eax
    movl varInputHandle, %ebx
    movl $varBuffer, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80

    #if no char was read (EOF?), jmp finishProcessing
    cmpl $0, %eax
    jz finishProcessing # looks like total success, finish cleanly

    cmpl $3, varBuffer   // this instruction is never true, don't know why
    je exitToOs
    #write it
    movl $4, %eax       
    movl varOutputHandle, %ebx     # file_descriptor
    movl $varBuffer, %ecx  
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80

    # done, go for the next char
    goForTheNextChar:
    jmp processingLoop

finishProcessing:
    movl $0, varExitCode #everything went OK, set exit code to 0

exitToOs:
    movl varOutputHandle, %ebx     # file_descriptor
    movl varInputHandle, %ebx    
    movl $1, %eax
    movl varExitCode, %ebx
    int $0x80

closeFile:
    cmpl $-1, %ebx
    movl $6, %eax  #sys_close
    int $0x80
```

`cmpl $3, varBuffer` seems to never be true therefore I can't jump to exitToOs.

Comment: You could have debugged this yourself by looking at the bytes in `varBuffer` yourself, e.g. with `x varBuffer` in gdb.  You would have noticed that they were ASCII encodings.

Comment: Also, `movl $0, cont` / ... / `incb cont` is probably a bug.  If possible, keep `cont` in a register.  `%esi` and `%edi` don't appear to be used in your code.

Comment: I see you did made my answer to your other question work, which I'm glad. But I see you did cut out some parts and changed some bits, in some cases to the worse, in some cases just not handling error states correctly. If you have particular problems with those omitted parts, you are welcome to comment back on the original question about it, so you understand it fully and make the code "work" in proper way, not only in some cases and by sheer luck. Also get debugger finally and learn how to use it. I would pay with gold for debugger back when I was learning Z80 ASM and I had to debug on paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
 cmpl $3, varBuffer
```

This can never be true because you do not have binary data in your file.

When you read character by character, you are reading ASCII values. In order to properly make this comparison you must do one of two things:

1. Convert the character read from ASCII to decimal
2. Compare the read value to an ASCII value

Since you are relying on $0 to identify when you have read zero bytes, I would suggest that you take the (easier) approach of checking for the ASCII value that you would like to find.  In your case this would be:

```
 cmpb $'3', varBuffer     # Compare character to 0x33 / 51 / "3"
```

Comment: I don't know this (AT&T syntax) assembler, but can one also write: `cmpl '3', varBuffer`, or is that not valid syntax? It would be a lot clearer that one is comparing with `'3'`, IMO.

Comment: And shouldn't that be `$0x33` or `$33h` instead of `$33`? The latter is probably just 33 (decimal).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes, in AT&T syntax you can write `cmpl $'3',  dst`.  Or to demonstrate a pointless use of more complex syntax, `cmpl $( 3 + '0' ), dst`.  I just tested, and `$33h` doesn't assemble.  `Error: junk 'h' after expression`

Comment: Thanks for the info. In that case, I would prefer $'3'.

Comment: I guess 33h is Intel only.

Comment: And how on earth `cmpl $'3'` will compare ASCII value, when ASCII is 8bit, not long? (I'm nitpicking on the **L** at the end of `cmpl`). Also he's not relying at $0 representing end of file. He's relaying on reading 0 bytes (that's the `cmpl $0, %eax` test) from input file handle.

Comment: Comparing '3' ahead of read bytes return value is maybe easier approach, but also less correct. If the file doesn't contain '3', the reading of file will go into infinite cycle. I don't see what's so complex about keeping everything as is, and just fix that original `cmpl $3` mistake, the OP almost nailed it on his own. Just that `cmp` should be `cmpb` (to test for 8 bit ASCII character) and $3 should be $'3'. The `cmpl $'3'` variant works only when the memory after the varBuffer contains accidentally three zero bytes.